# Python chart plot is empty

Tags: python, python-2.7, scatter-plot

When I call:

```
model = doKMeans(user3, 4)
```

and then

```
ax.scatter(model.cluster_centers_[:,1], model.cluster_centers_[:,0], 
           s=169, c='r', marker='x', alpha=0.8, linewidths=2)
```

and then:

```
showandtell("Weekday Calls Centroids")
```

my chart appears empty. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Welcome to SO. A few more details would be helpful to answer your question. What libraries (except matplotlib) are you using? Are you receiving any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue there is as simple as adding

```
plt.show()
```

to the end of your code.

Alternatively, another common mistake that might be causing that is that you if you are working on a jupyter notebook you might have forgot to add the command:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

when you import your matplotlib library

Hope that helps!